# How to change from using Servlet to Struts2?

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, struts

I am quite new to struts2. I have several Servlets in my web application and I wanted to change it so that I make use of the Struts2 framework. How do I go about doing this and keeping the same logic within the code? I am also using Hibernate and would also like to use Struts2 with Hibernate.

For instance, I have this servlet in my web application:

```
package com.webapp.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.webapp.entity.UserEntity;
import com.webapp.util.HibernateUtil;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SignUpServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/SignUpServlet")
public class SignUpServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SignUpServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doProcess(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doProcess(request, response);
    }


    protected void doProcess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("in process");
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String contactNo = request.getParameter("contactNo");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");

        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();

        userEntity.setUserName(userName);
        userEntity.setPassword(password);
        userEntity.setEmail(email);
        userEntity.setFirstName(firstName);
        userEntity.setLastName(lastName);
        userEntity.setAddress(address);
        userEntity.setContactNo(contactNo);

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(userEntity);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        response.sendRedirect("jsp/login.jsp");
    }
}
```

And the model

```
package com.webapp.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
 @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "userId")
private Long userId ;

@Column(name = "userName")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "roleId")
private Long roleId;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@Column(name = "contactNo")
private String contactNo;





public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getContactNo() {
    return contactNo;
}

public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
    this.contactNo = contactNo;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Long getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
}

public void setRoleId(Long roleId) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

And the view which is SignUp.jsp

```
<head>
     </head>
        <body>

            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <table width="" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0"
                   cellspacing="0" class="maintable">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="center" class="middlesection">
                        <table width="96%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"
                                                       cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                                            <h1>
                                                                Sign Up
                                                            </h1>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                                                            <table width="0%" border="0" cellspacing="0"
                                                                   cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center" style="color: #00FF00">
                                                                        &nbsp;
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <a href="#" class="buttonash" onclick="resetForm();"><span>
                                                                                reset </span> </a>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td width="5"></td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <a href="#" class="buttonash" onclick="submit()"><span>
                                                                                SignUp </span> </a>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="bottomboder">
                                                <img src="/WebApp/images/ashish.gif" height="1" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="tab-content-out" style="clear: both">
                                        <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
                                            <div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">

                                                <div
                                                    style="background: url(/WebApp/images/tabhdbg.gif) top repeat-x #ffffff; height: 70px;"
                                                    class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
                                                    <div style="width: 1px; float: left;">
                                                        <img src="/WebApp/images/tabhdline.gif" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="navi"
                                                         style="padding-left: 7px; padding-top: 9px;">
                                                        <div style="color: #4B5974; font-size: 24px;"
                                                             align="center">
                                                            <b>  SignUp Form</b>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div style="width: 1px; float: right;">
                                                        <img src="images/tabhdline.gif" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
                                                <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
                                                    <div style="border: 0;" class="tab-content">
                                                        <div class="entry-edit">
                                                            <div class="tebelhd" align="left">
                                                                General Information
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="fieldset" id="_generalbase_fieldset">
                                                                <div class="hor-scroll" align="left">
                                                                    <table class="form-list" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                        <form method="get" id="addCustomer" name="addCustomer" action="/WebApp/SignUpServlet"  >
                                                                        <table>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <label>First Name</label>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <input type="text"  name="firstName" required size="51" class="required-entry required-entry input-text"/>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <label>Last Name</label>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <input type="text"  name="lastName" size="51" class="required-entry required-entry input-text"/>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <label>Adddress</label>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <input type="text"  name="address" size="51" class="required-entry required-entry input-text"/>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <label>Contact No.</label>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <input type="text"  name="contactNo" size="51" class="required-entry required-entry input-text"/>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <label>Email</label>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <input type="text"  name="email" size="51" class="required-entry required-entry input-text"/>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <label>UserName</label>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <input type="text"  name="userName" size="51" class="required-entry required-entry input-text"/>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <label>Password</label>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <input type="password"  name="password" size="51" class="required-entry required-entry input-text"/>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                             </form>

                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

1. Do not start by randomly editing stuff in your application, it will lead to a world of pain.
2. [Read a Tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-17), to get at least the minimal notion about the workflow.
3. Create a sample Struts2 project with Maven and one of the Struts2 archetype, maybe the Blank Convention Archetype; make it running, then try changing something, take at least some hour to understand the basics.
4. Dive into Struts documentation for each doubt, to go deeply on the basics. Always remember that every Action runs through an Interceptor Stack (a customizable list of Interceptors, each one doing a different business), before and after getting called, and that Actions are created per-user-per-request and hence are Thread Safe, while Interceptors are NOT Thread Safe.

[image]

After a couple of days of fun, you can start editing your own big project.

In older versions, Struts2 had the Actions mapped in a file called `struts.xml`, but with Convention plugin there is no need to do that, the Actions will be mapped basing on their method name (or with `@Action` annotation).

Then

- get rid of your `doGet()` and `doPost()` methods
- change `doProcess()` to `newActionName()`, that will become the name of the Action, or put `@Action(value="newActionName")` over each `doProcess()` method
- map the results (normal or redirectAction) for your Actions, and remove all the references to the `response` object inside the servlets.

If your project is big, you don't know Struts2 and you will try to start this conversion without taking a couple of days to learn it, you will lose more days later, with worse results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I used before, it was very useful.

[Tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-struts2-hibernate-example-eclipse/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: `ActionServlet`? Where did you find such class?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/api/org/apache/struts/action/ActionServlet.html Google it :)

Comment: OP question is about Struts2.